# In Blazor, how can I at runtime see what child or parent components there are of the current component?

Tags: blazor

With Blazor, suppose I am writing tools that want to examine the parent or child components of a given component at runtime.  Is there any way to know, at runtime, **what components are children of the current component**? Alternatively, is there any way to know, without passing in via parameters, **what component is the parent** of the current component?  Even just the name of the parent component might be useful.

I am thinking about collecting data on rerender counts and render times; part of this is just exploring what is possible in Blazor without a certain specific end goal.

I thought about writing an abstract class, e.g. `DataCollectingComponentBase`, that inherits from ComponentBase and perhaps creating a overridable CascadingValue with the name AncestorName as well as a CascadingParameter also called `AncestorName`, but I don't see any way to specify a CascadingValue or even [any template in a base component](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21664), and anyway, it would perhaps be a bad approach to require every component to inherit from such a class.  So I'm not sure I should pursue that way.

A better approach might be to inspect the RenderTree, but I don't see anything exposed for me to do so.  Some kind of recursive RenderTree property on ComponentBase might be nice, but no such luck.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to do this during application/unit testing or is this part of your live application?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I think the best answer is this comment from Steve: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26826#issuecomment-708403993  
In case you want to know which is the parent I think the only method is to using a cascadingparameter with a `Value="this"` and all the children will know the parent.  
From the children than you'll can call a method to the parent to communicate the children names.

Comment: It won't be a part of my application proper, I just want to use it temporarily to gain insight about how rerenders relate to parents and children.

Comment: I thought about using a cascading value but there seems to be no way to do that without adding such a CascadingValue to every component whose children I want to examine.  I don't see a way to add a CascadingValue to a base class, do you?